What is this texture for in my imported model, and how do I connect it?

I can't figure out what it is and how to attach it? Thank you in advance for your help.

Hello and welcome. This question seems off topic here, it is probably best asked at the community for the undisclosed origin of the imported model

On a guess, the green channel is Roughness, and the blue channel is M for Metallic, hence the RM suffix. The red channel could be a bump map.

Add an Image Texture node, select this image, and set the color space non-color data (default is sRGB).
Use a Separate Color node to break the color output into the red, green, and blue components.
Plug the green and blue components into the Roughness and Metallic inputs of the Principled BSDF node, respectively.
Run the red channel through a Bump node as the Height value, and plug that into the Principled shader’s Normal vector input.



Although I agree that the channels are probably maps for roughness and metallic, why does the red channel appear unused to you? The red channel is the reason for the yellow and purple areas... I could not tell from the image if that does not serve any purpose.

Pretty sure the red channel is a bump map

@GordonBrinkmann oh, sorry, I was colorblind last I checked. I didn’t see it.
